# Include a raw js library in my ember cli project

Tags: ember-cli

I would like to simply download this library and include it in my ember cli project.

It is not available as a bower package, what should I do?

https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax.git

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do:

`bower install --save appendto/jquery-mockjax`

You may notice this uses `github-user/repository-name`

**Brocfile.js:**

```
app.import( 'bower_components/jquery-mockjax/jquery.mockjax.js' );
```