# Unable to use PikaDay component in Ember project

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I downloaded pikaday.js and put it my app's views directory, one of my view code looks like

```
var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: formElement,
    format: "MM/DD/YYYY",
    firstDay: 1,
    .
    .
    .
});
```

I tried all possible ways to include the external javascript pikaday.js to my ember project but I still continue to get the error:
'Pikaday' is not defined

Kindly let me know how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you use `<script...>` to include the file in your page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include a raw js library in my ember cli project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665864/include-a-raw-js-library-in-my-ember-cli-project)

Comment: Have you tried the ember-pikaday addon for ember-cli?